# How to pass in variable to Selenium to find presence of element in Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Wondering if someone could help me.

I'm trying to pass a variable into the EC.presence_of_element_located condition but I'm getting an argument error which I'm not sure how to resolve.

Error is below

> "TypeError: presence_of_element_located() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

To find an element you must pass in the type (ID, XPATH etc) and the name of the element I believe.

`WebDriverWait(context.driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.ID,Selectors.LOGIN))`

In my Selectors file that contains the variable I have the following code

`LOGIN = Selector("//*[@id=login-button")` also tried LOGIN = Selector("login-button")`

The element does exist because if I use (By.ID,"login-button") it works fine.

Here is my code

login.py

```
import os
from behave import *
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import sys
sys.path.append("..")

from features.selectors import Selectors

@given("the user is on the login screen")
def login_screen(context):
    context.driver.get("http://localhost:3000")
    try:
      WebDriverWait(context.driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.ID,Selectors.LOGIN))
    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Timed out")

@when("the user clicks the login button")
def click_login(context):
    context.driver.find_element(By.ID,Selectors.LOGIN).click()
```

selectors.py

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class Selector:
    def __init__(self, value: str):
        self.value = value


class Selectors:
    

# Initial Login Page

    LOGIN = Selector("//*[@id=login-button")
```

Does anyone know how this is done? I've tried so many combinations now that my brain is fried

I've tried various combinations of the above code but unable to get the correct syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument passed into Expected Conditions is supposed to be a tuple, written as:

```
[...]
WebDriverWait(context.driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,Selectors.LOGIN)))
[...]
```

Sadly, [Selenium documentation on waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) does not mention it clearly.

Comment: Thanks Barry, much appreciated. This worked for me. Just a follow up question. I have another condition "find_element" and I've used the same syntax but getting the error 

" selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: Unable to determine element locating strategy"

This is the line of code 

driver.find_element((Selectors.LOGIN)).click()

I've also tried 

driver.find_element(Selectors.LOGIN).click()

Thanks

Comment: Sorry Barry for more context I was testing moving the By.ID to the selectors.py file which worked for the expected conditions but not the find element condition. 

LOGIN = Selector(By.ID,"//*[@id=login-button")

Comment: When I try "context.

driver.find_element(By.ID,Selectors.LOGIN).click() i get the following error

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

{"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="('id', 'login-button')"]"}

Comment: It is always advisable to wait for the elements in page to fully load: that's why we have waits in Selenium. The fact you cannot find that element without waiting for it means the element is being dynamically loaded in page.

Comment: Yeah I'm adding in a WebDriverWait condition and setting the value to 20 so it should detect the element in the line 

 WebDriverWait(context.driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,Selectors.LOGIN)))

And then I'm trying to find the element and select it. 

driver.find_element(By.ID,Selectors.LOGIN).click()

Comment: You seem a bit confused, @ChrisF: your first line of code, where you are waiting for the element, is actually selecting the element. You don;t need to search for it again.

Comment: Yeah I have split them out but updated this so the first line of code also clicks the button. Thanks